# Proof about rational sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

I'm stuck on part (iii). I wanted to use induction, but i'm having trouble proving the base case, which I took as n=3. Perhaps this was the wrong idea, but we'll see.

The only thing we know anything is $x_1$, so I wrote $x_3$ in terms of $x_2$ which I in turn wrote in terms of $x_1$.

I've reduced the expression of $x_3$ down to:

$$ {\large x_3} = \frac{\dfrac{x_1^{4}}{2} + ax_1^{2} + \dfrac{a^{2}}{2} + ax_1}{x_1^{2} +a}$$

but I still don't see how I can get the result I want. I was thinking of taking a limit, but $x_1$ is fixed, can I take a limit on $a$?

Comment: also if anyone can edit that latex to make my espression for $x_3$ bigger that would be great. idk why it's so small.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We want to show first that $x_2^2 \ge a$. (We have $x_2^2=a$  if $x_1=\sqrt{a}$.) So we want to show that
$$\left(\frac{x_1^2+a}{2x_1}\right)^2\ge a.$$
Equivalently, we want to show that
$$(x_1^2+a)^2\ge 4x_1^2 a,$$
or equivalently that 
$$(x_1^2-a)^2\ge 0.$$
This is obvious.

I will stop here. The induction step is essentially a repeat of the above, and does not even use the induction hypothesis!

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure $x_1$ can't equal $a$. wouldn't this be the same as the square root of a which isn't rational for all a?

Comment: I had a typo, it is $x_1=\sqrt{a}$. The square root of $a$ is for example rational if $a=9$, or if $a=\frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: but if $a=2$, then it's not rational, and $x_1$ must be rational

Comment: If we use the algorithm to approximate $\sqrt{9}$ and make initial "guess" $x_1=3$, then we will get $x_2=3$, $x_3=3$, and so on.

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I am saying that the $x_n^2 \gt a$ is not necessarily true. It is always true if $\sqrt{a}$ is irrational. And if $\sqrt{a}$ is rational, it is true if we start with $x_1\ne \sqrt{a}$. But I am being fussy, and saying we do not **always** have strict inequality.

Comment: hmm, you're right, but I should probably talk to my professor about that. It's not clear whether he wants  us to assume that $\sqrt{a}$ is irrational or not..

Comment: Well, it says let $a\gt 0$ be a real number. You can either observe $\lt$ is not quite right, but $\le $ is always right. You can further observe that $\lt $ is right for any choice of $x_1$ if $\sqrt{a}$ is irrational, and also for $\sqrt{a}$ rational as long as $x_1\ne \sqrt{a}$. Anyway, the important thing is the basic argument, which (in my version) uses the fact that any square is non-negative. *Exactly* the same argument will take you from $k$ to $k+1$.

Comment: No worries, I understand your proof and all the logic, im just confused now with the discrepancy of this problem; ill need to clear it up with my professor.

Answer (score 0):

An idea putting $\;x_0:=a\;$:

$$x_1:=\frac{x_0^2+a}{2x_0}=\frac{a+1}{2}\implies x_2^2=\left(\frac{x_1^2+a}{2x_1}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\frac{(a+1)^2}4+a}{a+1}\right)^2=\left(\frac{a^2+6a+1}{4a+4}\right)^2$$

Thus, we get that

$$x_2^2>a\iff\frac1{16}(a^2+6a+1)^2>a(a+1)^2\iff$$

$$\iff a^4+12a^3+2a^2+36a^2+12a+1>16a^3+32a^2+16a\iff$$

$$\iff a^4-4a^3+6a^2-4a+1>0\iff (a-1)^4>0$$

Comment: well, it's fine with $x_0$ = a, but I need to consider all cases too, less than, greater than...

also, $x_1$ is the starting estimate so $x_0$ doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Well, there **must** be a $\;x_0\;$ otherwise the sequence is ill-defined: what is $\;x_1\;$ and thus what is the *whole* sequence ?! And if it doesn't really matter what positive value we choose for this, then we can as well choose $\;x_0=a\;$ ...

Comment: well if there is $x_0$ does this mean there is $x_-1$? I thought that the standard sequence went from $n=1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: If there is no $\;x_0\;$ then how in the word is defined $\;x_1\;$ **according to your** formula??

Comment: $x_1$ must be given to us. this sequence is created using Newton's Method, which needs a starting value to start computing estimations.

Comment: Great, @terribleatmath ! Then in my answer move all the indexes one up and "define" $\;x_1=a\;$ !

Comment: I realize that it works, but this proof requires for ANY choice of $x_1$. $x_1 = a$ is just one choice.

Comment: And that is why I wrote "if it doesn't really matter...", as in some approximation methods. And as pointed out by Andre, it isn't true for *some* choices of $\;a\;$ ...